# How to ask someone to put food in my plate for me?

Tags: sentence-construction

If i am having dinner in my friend's house and I want them to put some salad in my plate for me because the container carrying the salad is too far away from me,
 what is the correct way to construct the sentence?

Can  I simply say

> Can you put some salad in my plate?

or does the below option also work

> Can you fill my plate with some salad?

Comment: Would you not ask them to pass you the salad container? Also, it would be '***on** my plate*' and not '***in** my plate*' (it would only be *in* if it was into a *bowl*)

Comment: Or, if the salad bowl is too big to pass, 'Can you serve me with some salad, please?'

Answer (score 2):

"Fill" means *to capacity*. It doesn't sound right to ask for your plate to be "filled" with "some". Filling anything requires as much as is necessary.

If you want an entire plate of salad, with no room for anything else, ask "can you fill my plate with salad". Note that, if you already had something else on your plate, "filling" it would mean filling the remaining space.

"Some" salad means an unspecified quantity. When talking about food, it would be taken to mean "a portion". While portion sizes vary in different situations, it would be whatever is considered by the server to be a reasonable amount.